# How to extract a series of string within text in dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, extract

I'm new to panda and python, need your help on how can i code this in the panda to extract `gA636000000420n` and `http://help.sf.com` from the following string in dataframe:

```
https://my.sf.com/gA636000000420n?lang=en_US
http://help.sf.com/en/sf/12.0/configuration-guide-pdf.pdf
```

search and return using above 2 conditions in one new column together like if `"http://help.sf.com"` found then return `'http://help.sf.com'`, else if found `gA636000000420n` then return `gA636000000420n` else "Others"

found 
`df.str.['column'].str.extract()` but not able to find more example of it how to use it in my case. Thanks for your help

Comment: `https://my.sf.com/gA636000000420n?lang=en_US http://help.sf.com/en/sf/12.0/configuration-guide-pdf.pdf` is this a single string or two strings ?

Comment: its 2 strings, one row after another

Comment: @TVD you need str.extract with a pattern, check answer below and let me know if you need anything

Comment: my apoligies, these data only in one series

Comment: Url name:                                                                             Extracted column

https://my.sf.com/gA636000000420n?lang=en_US           "gA636000000420n" http://help.sf.com/en/sf/12.0/configuration-guide-pdf.pdf   "help" 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=39J2HdPka_JE        "youtube"
https://my.sf.com/gA896000000670n?lang=en_US         "gA896000000670n"
https://my.sf.com/gA694000029420n?lang=en_SP         " gA694000029420n"
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IHG2HdPka_JE        "youtube"

Comment: @TVD check edited answer. I think I have addressed what you meant, let me know if not.

Comment: @anky_91 thanks for the update.  what happened if I have a big list lets say > 10000.  Define in "my_list = ['gA636000000420n','help','youtube','gA896000000670n','gA694000029420n']" is not user friendly.  "Help.sf.com" & "youtube.com" may work but the 15 digit starts with "gA" will not be.  Any other alternative? Thanks

Comment: Where have you stored the look up values. In a different column?

Comment: Not sure if I understood your question properly, but there is only 1 column in this dataframe which is the data what we want to extract from.  There is no lookup values, it just the pattern we want to extract and store in new column.  Hope it makes sense. Thanks

Comment: Thank you all, issue resolved now.